# xcodebuild has a exit status 1 when succeed

Tags: ios, iphone, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I build my iOS app on CI using

```
xcodebuild clean build  -workspace "$PROJECT_WORKSPACE_NAME" -scheme "$PROJECT_NAME" CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED="NO"
```

the build succeeds but still exits with error 1

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: whats the reason for CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED to set NO ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- **Delete** **derivedData** *folder* then *empty trash*.
- **clean** `your_project` by clicking **cmd** + **shift** + **k**.
- **Uninstall**  **Application** from **device**.
- then `Rebuild`.

,and all Done :)